# Summer Mathematics Workbooks for Elementary and Middle School

Tags: education, mathematics

There is a wide variety of summer mathematics workbooks available for students in elementary and middle school (see [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=summer%20math%20workbook)). With summer coming up, these books seem to be available everywhere. Thus my questions are:

**Is there any evidence that suggests summer workbooks are beneficial for average students?**

---

Note: This question was posted on Matheducators.SE but received limited attention. I suspect it may be better suited for this site.